# Sympy simplify sine

Tags: sympy, simplify

I try to simplify the following equation

> f = 1/(2*i) *(E**(i*x)-E**(-i*x))

So I wrote this code:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import x
init_printing(use_unicode=False, wrap_line=False, no_global=True)

f = 1/(2*I) *(E**(I*x)-E**(-I*x))

trigsimp(f)
```

I want to get the result as the sine-function, because

> 1/(2*I) *(E**(I*x)-E**(-I*x)) = sine(x)

Does anyone know, how to get the results simplified as sine, cos... -function?

Many thanks in advance!

John

Comment: Again as with your last question: Tell sympy everything you know. Instead of `from sympy.abc import x` use `x = symbols('x', real=True)`. This makes it easier for sympy and for other users trying to understand your question. Also try and play around with `x.assumptions0` after defining `x` both ways.
Answer from smichr is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f.rewrite(sin)` should do it. This is an example of the rewriting capabilities. Whenever you think something can be rewritten in terms of something else, try this method.